# Screen size issue on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, screen-size

I have the following implementation for a custom header view in a table view :

```
// Create Label
let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(32,8,100,36))
label.text = title

// Create top dark grey rectangle
let headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(17, 8, 130, 36))
headerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Section Header")

// Create top rounded corner view with 16px margins
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
let sectionTopImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(16, 44, width-32, 4))
sectionTopImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Header Rounded Corners")

// Wrap it up
let headerView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0, width, 48))
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
headerView.addSubview(headerImageView)
headerView.addSubview(sectionTopImageView)
headerView.addSubview(label)

return headerView
```

So basically I want to have a header that has 16px margin on both sides. In Storyboard I have a cell with a background `UIImageView`. This image view has auto layout constraints so that I get my 16 margins px there too.

Everything should be aligned but when I run simulator or real iPhone, I get this for iPhone 6 and smaller screen size :
[image: iPhone 6 and smaller : problem]

But for iPhone 6 Plus, everything is perfectly aligned :
[image: iPhone 6 plus : works fine]

Any idea why ?

**EDIT**

I add here the code for the background image of the cell. For subclassing reason I removed the create of this background from storyboard to code. Here is what I came up with :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectionStyle = .None
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let height = self.contentView.bounds.size.height

    backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(16, 0, width - 32, height+1))
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cell Background")

    self.insertSubview(backgroundImageView, atIndex: 0)
}
```

I have the same issue with this code as previously. But whereas this line from @robmayoff solved it :

```
sectionTopImageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth]
```

The same line here :

```
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth]
```

Causes this weird behavior :
[image]

Comment: In what function did you put all this code?

Comment: @robmayoff `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't accurately measure the sizes of things in your screen shots because they appear to have been resized. That makes it harder to help you.

Nevertheless, I think you may have better results if you set the autoresizing mask on your subview before adding it to the header view:

```
sectionTopImageView.autoresizingMask = [ .FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin ]
```

#### UPDATE

In `awakeFromNib`, `self` has whatever size it had in the storyboard or xib. It hasn't yet been resized for the device screen or the table view or whatever.

You're sizing `backgroundImageView` based on the device screen size, which (at that point) has nothing to do with `self.bounds.size`.

If you think `backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width` should be 32 points less than `self.bounds.size.width`, then set it that way:

```
backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(16, 0, bounds.size.width - 32, height+1))
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. It worked ! I tried to remove `.FlexibleTopMargin`and it worked too. But could you explain me why it did ? (And why it did not before) Moreover, it seems not to work when similar code is applied inside an `awakeFromNib` function.

Comment: The table view resizes the header view to fit the table. It's making the header view wider. By setting `.FlexibleWidth`, you're telling the image view to become wider by the same amount. I don't know why the header view needs to be resized but apparently it does. You'd have to edit your question to include the `awakeFromNib` code if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers !